# strange bone alignment

Tags: bones

If I click the bone and press g, and press ctrl, it creates an orange line and aligns in a strange direction. Why is that? It was originally arranged at right angles by pressing the ctrl key.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What CTRL does is determined in the very center of the top of your screen. It's a snapping tool and what it snaps to can be selected next to the magnet icon. ATM you're snapping to the closest face. You may want to set that to Edge Perpendicular.